# Hover over image changes another image

Tags: html, css, class, hover, effect

I got a problem - I'm trying to force image hover to affect another hover

```
<img id="1" src="#" />
<img id="2" src="#" />


#1 {width:20%;
    opacity:0.5
   }
#2 {width:80%;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
   }
```

i tried

```
#1:hover + #2{
   display:block;
   }

  #1:hover #2{
   display:block;
   }
```

tried putting it into different divs but it still won't work.
Can someone help?

Comment: You can use jQuery as well for this. A similar question has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050860/change-an-image-src-within-a-div-when-hovering-over-another-div

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I couldn't get css to work with the `id="1"` or `id="2"` but once changed to `id="test2"` it worked fine.